# Test data for unique and not null

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can I quickly check to see if the data from the test table 'test_table', and selected columns are unique and not null.
Summary, at the entrance gets a table name and a list of columns in the output are expected , eg . flag 1 or 0.
Table is big so unfortunately i must posibly fast execute;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 1 from dual
where exsist (select col1,col2,col3,... from table
where col1 is not null and col2 is not null and col3....
group by col1,col2,col3.. having count(*) > 1 )
```

this will return 1 when one of the is true.

Comment: but your first sql find only unique values and have null values but that and all your query is ralativly slow

Comment: and i would like to create one sql or procedure who return flag witch a use next

Comment: thanks that is good answer but  execution time is probably low, if i can somehow improve or change 2 000 000+ rows

Comment: i checked it with 15mil records table, took 20 seconds. Are you looking for something faster than that? @AdamNowak

Comment: Try analytical function ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COL1,COL2,COL3....ORDER BY COL DESC) RNK

Comment: @sagi why in your query in first select in exist not addet where clausule witch not null and eliminate second query from exists

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 1
FROM   dual
WHERE  EXISTS
 (SELECT a, b FROM   tab  WHERE  id=1
        AND    name='John'
        AND    (a IS NULL OR b IS NULL))
```

I changed your code and I have one question about it , now I have is that id must be 1 and the name 'John ' and any of verifying null must be correct, and wants to have that must be id = 1 and the name 'John ' and if there is either the value of the column is ' null'

Comment: Insertion of uniq and not null is still valid , I would like to request return 1 in these cases and additionally studied only id = 1 and name ' John '